# How to represent a family relationship in Django using manyToMany and inlineformset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, manytomanyfield

I would like to create a update view where a Person model has their related FamilyMember as an inlineformset in my template.

In my model.py, I have:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='PersonFamilyMember')
    relationType= models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=FAMILYRELATION_CHOICE)

class PersonFamilyMember(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related = models.ForeignKey(FamilyMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my form.py, I have:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class FamilyMemberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FamilyMember
        fields = '__all__'

RelatedFMFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Person, PersonFamilyMember.useCase.through,                                          form=FamilyMemberForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

In my view.py, I have:

```
class PersonView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'some.html'
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['familymember_form'] = RelatedFMFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,
                                                                   instance=self.object, prefix='relatedMember')
        else:
            context['familymember_form'] = RelatedFMFormSet(instance=self.object, prefix='relatedMember')
        return context
```

In my template, I have:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px">    
    {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}      
    {% endfor %}    
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>[Person Profile][1]</legend>
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {{ form.non_form_errors }}
    <div class="form-inline">       
            {% bootstrap_form  form %}
            </div>          
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Related Member(s)</legend>
        {{ familymember_form.management_form }}
        {{ familymember_form.non_form_errors }}
        <div class="formset-{{ relatedusecase_form.prefix }}">
            {% for hidden_field in familymember_form.hidden_fields %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for relatedform in familymember_form.forms %}
                <div class="form-inline">
                    {% if relatedform.instance.pk %}
                        {{ relatedform.DELETE }}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ relatedform }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </fieldset>
<!--Other Code--!>
</form>
```

With the code segments above, when I render the template, I getting(see image in the link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6OEp.jpg):

As a result, I cannot click on the related dropdown to select the related Person. Also, the related type is not display in the template either.

Comment: So a FamilyMember is not a Person? And for all Persons a FamilyMember is related to, it has the same relationship type? Also you're not showing us the `UseCaseProfileRelatedUseCase` model. It seems to me your models don't match with what you intend to do.

Comment: The FamilyMember should show the Persons that are related to another Person. For example, if there is a (Person) Phil, some FamilyMember could be James (Person) with relationType (Brother) or Janine(Person) with relationType (Sister). I removed the UseCaseProfileRelatedUseCase model and replaced it with PersonFamilyMember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two models, not 3, because you're actually relating a Person to a Person.

```
class Person(Model):
    name = ...
    family_members = ManyToManyField('self', through=FamilyMemberRelationship, through_fields=('person', 'relation'))

class FamilyMemberRelationship(Model):
    person = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='relationships')
    related = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='reverse_relationships')
    relation_type = CharField(max_length=3, choices=FAMILYRELATION_CHOICE)
```

Note that the relationship is not symmetrical. Now if you have `phil` and `james` is Phil's brother, then you can do:

```
relation = FamilyMemberRelationship(person=phil, related=james, relation_type='brother')
relation.save()
phil.family_members.all()  # james
phil.relations.filter(related=james).first().relation_type  # "brother" 
james.family_members.all()  # phil
```

The only thing here is that the relation_type has a direction (is not symmetrical), so you can't:

```
james.relations.filter(related=phil).first()  # None
```

but you can:

```
james.reverse_relations.filter(related=phil).first().relation_type  # "brother"
```

You might want to also save a `reverse_relation_type` so you could have 'sister' there if `phil` was a girl.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on how to represent the models. However, when I do: **class P(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields='__all__'    class FMForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UseCaseRelationship
        fields='__all__'   RelatedPersonFormset= inlineformset_factory(Person.family_members.through, FamilyMemberRelationship,
                                         form=FMForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)** I get ValueError: 'FamilyMemberRelationship' has no ForeignKey to 'FamilyMemberRelationship'.